# ColdFusion syntax error when using data from one query in another query

Tags: coldfusion, syntax-error

I have the following code below, which is supposed to get student information based on their parking permit number:

```
<cfparam name="Permit" default="">

<cfquery name="q_sample" datasource="cars_live">
  SELECT * FROM veh_rec WHERE UPPER(DECAL) LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#trim(urldecode(UCase(Permit)))#">
</cfquery>

<cfif q_sample.recordcount eq 0> 
No Results found for <cfoutput>"#Permit#"</cfoutput> 
</cfif>

<cfquery name="s_sample" datasource="cars_live">
  SELECT FULLNAME FROM id_rec WHERE ID = #q_sample.ID#>
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="s_sample">
  <p>Name: #FULLNAME#<p>
</cfoutput>

<cfoutput query="q_sample" >
  <p>License Plate Number: #license# <br><br> Permit ID Number: #decal#<br><br> Student ID Number: #ID# <br><br> Academic years: #ACADYR#<br><br></p>
</cfoutput>
```

The license plate, permit ID number, and such all work fine, but when I try to use the #q_sample.ID# tag, I get a syntax error. However when I look at the error in chrome's console window, I can see that it is getting the correct ID based on the permit number. Not sure why this is happening. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

as requested:

Error:

```
The web site you are accessing has experienced an unexpected error.
Please contact the website administrator. 

The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.
Error Occurred While Processing Request
Error Executing Database Query.

A syntax error has occurred.

The error occurred in /d2/www/vhosts/joeyP.cfm: line 11
9 : 10 : <cfquery name="s_sample" datasource="cars_live">11 :   SELECT FULLNAME FROM id_rec WHERE ID = #q_sample.ID#>12 : </cfquery>13 : 

VENDORERRORCODE   -201

SQLSTATE      42000

SQL    SELECT FULLNAME FROM id_rec WHERE ID = 371043>

DATASOURCE    cars_live

Resources:

Check the ColdFusion documentation to verify that you are using the correct syntax.
Search the Knowledge Base to find a solution to your problem.

Browser     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36

Remote Address      10.200.168.210

Referrer    http://{redacted}/tests/yup.html

Date/Time   10-Jun-13 09:17 AM

Stack Trace
at cfjoeyP2ecfm876470777.runPage(/d2/www/vhosts/joeyP.cfm:11) at cfjoeyP2ecfm876470777.runPage(/d2/www/vhosts/joeyP.cfm:11)
```

number I was testing was 371043

Comment: Please post the full error message and the actual value of `#q_sample.ID#` when the error occurs. (Though there is really no need for two (2) queries. Just use a `JOIN` between the two tables on the `id` column.)

Comment: I added the info!

And I guess I could look up join and use that. This just seemed easier.

Comment: Conceptually yes, but in terms of code a `join` is simpler IMO. Plus you eliminate an extra db call. BTW: 1) Since you are searching for an exact match, the query should use `=` rather than  `like` 2) Do not forget to scope your variables ie `URL.permit` 3) You rarely need `urlDecode`. CF decodes URL variables automatically 4) It is a good practice to always use cfqueryparam on *all* variable query parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extraneious `>` at the end of this query. If you take that out it should fix your issue.

```
<cfquery name="s_sample" datasource="cars_live">
SELECT FULLNAME FROM id_rec WHERE ID = #q_sample.ID#>
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Just found it myself... How embarassing! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. If I have a syntax error and it ends up being with `<` or `>` I tend to gloss over them when using ColdFusion because they're used so frequently.